# Как проверить все ли элементы в массиве numpy одинаковые? Python

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, numpy

Дан массив:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

```
[1 0 1 1 0]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно проверить одинаковые ли все элементы в массиве или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант (`np.unique(array).size`), который возвращает количество уникальных элементов массива (вне зависимости от размерности). Если это количество больше 1, то, очевидно, не все элементы одинаковы:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
b = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,0,1]])
c = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])

print(np.unique(a).size)
print(np.unique(b).size)
print(np.unique(c).size)
```

Соответственно, получим:

```
2
2
1
```

Comment: Ваше решение в 20-30 раз медленнее на массиве из 1 миллиона элементов, чем `np.all`. Результаты сравнения в ответе ниже.

Comment: Ну так это и не удивительно, правда?

Answer (score 3):

`np.all(a == a[0])`

Выражение внутри скобок строит массив из значений `True`, если соответствующий элемент равен `a[0]`, и `False` в противном случае. `npa.all` возвращает `True` если все элементы в этом массиве равны `True`.

Работает даже в случае многомерных массивов.

UPDATE

Сравнение производительности с решением из принятого ответа. Массив длиной 1 миллион элементов, в котором элемент на позиции 500_000 отличается от остальных.
`np.all` оказался в **25+ раз быстрее**, чем `np.unique`

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)
IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.full(1000000, 1)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])

In [4]: x[500000]=0

In [6]: np.unique(x).size
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: %timeit np.unique(x).size
100 loops, best of 3: 9.26 ms per loop

In [8]: np.all(x == x[0])
Out[8]: False

In [9]: %timeit np.all(x == x[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 420 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.all(x == x[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 µs per loop
```